# Getting the coordinates of the corners of cells in the MGRS coordinate system

Tags: python, grid, maps, coordinates

I'm hoping to find a reference where, given a coordinate in the MGRS convention (e.g., 18SUH 67890 43210 ), is there a database or algorithm such that I can find the coordinates of the approximate 'corners' of the cell?  I know that not all of these cells are actually rectangular, just hoping to get the coordinates of the four corners.  Would prefer to do this in Python, but open to any suggestions.

Comment: `coordinates` - like latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mgrs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mgrs) will convert to latitude and longitude.  The grid reference is the southwest corner. To get the other three just add one to the easting and/or northing:

```
18SUH 67890 43210 
northwest  = 18SUH 67890 43211
southeast = 18SUH 67891 43210
northeast = 18SUH 67891 43211
```

This would serve for simple solutions, it might not work in the polar regions.